# Voltage source connected in parallel to a resistor

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I am not sure how to treat the parallel branch circled in red. Could someone please explain? I am trying to solve it using Kirchoff's voltage law.

Comment: what about the other parallel branches?

Comment: Don't be confused by the way it is drawn. Redraw it if necessary. And when I say mean redraw, I mean on paper, not in your head. You won't have enough experience to do it in your head. I've talked to students where I repeatedly said redraw it, and they kept trying to cut corners and rearrange the circuit in their head instead, and kept getting it wrong, not realizing they didn't have enough experience to do it in their head yet. So even if you *think* you can, draw it on paper until you *know* you can.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Break the circuit into 3 clear loops:
I1, I2, and I3.

Create a system of equations for each loop.
I1(R1 + R2 + R3) - I2(R2) + I3(0) = E2 - E1
-I1(R2) + I2(R2 + R5) - I3(R5) = -E2
I1(0) - I2(R5) + I3(R4 + R5) = -E3

Insert your values and solve the system of equations to determine the current through each loop:
I1 = -1.69A, I2 = -8.06A, I3 = -4.81A

The sum of currents through any component can be used to determine the voltage drop through that component using Ohm's Law.  i.e. V[R5] = (I2-I3)R5

Results confirmed with simulation via Multisim (image)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Clearly identify loops and do not think about branches. Write equations, just as you would write on paper. Notice and study voltage source values and polarities.

```
eq1 = -E1 + ia R1 + (ia - ib) R2 + E2  + ia R3 == 0;
eq2 = (ib - ic) R5 - E2 + (ib - ia) R2 == 0;
eq3 = ic R4 - E3 + (ic - ib) R5 == 0;
```

Solve:

```
sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {ia, ib, ic}]
```

Assign values to components: (Advantage of this approach is that you can change component values later without having to change equations you wrote above.

```
comps = {R1 -> 12, R2 -> 10, R3 -> 8, R4 -> 20, R5 -> 5, E1 -> 50, 
   E2 -> 80, E3 -> 80};

sol[[1]] /. comps // N
```

> {ia -> 1.6875, ib -> 8.0625, ic -> 4.8125}

---

Simplified eqns for a paper and pencil solution (this particular case):

> ```
> {50 + 10 ib == 80 + 30 ia, 80 + 10 ia + 5 ic == 15 ib, 
>  80 + 5 ib == 25 ic}
> ```

Once the solution for loop currents is there, it is not that difficult to find any voltage drop or branch currents.

**EDIT Alt solution**

Of course you wouldn't select these as meshes of your first choice: but as long as all components have not become part of the equations at least once, you have to keep adding meshes. Let's write three equations for this scenario. Select different names for currents to keep your sanity.

[image]

```
eq1 = -E1 + ip R1 + (ip + iq + ir) R4 - E3 + ip R3 == 0;
eq2 = -E2 + iq R2 + (ip + iq + ir) R4 - E3 == 0;
eq3 = ir R5 + (ip + iq + ir) R4 - E3 == 0;

sol2 = Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {ip, iq, ir}]
sol2[[1]] /. comps // N
```

> {ip -> 1.6875, iq -> 6.375, ir -> -3.25}

Now calculate all resistor voltages as an exercise for this scenario and convince yourself that it works.